# How do I execute a query with an advanced ORDER BY situation?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a question about a query in MySQL i am trying to do. Suppose i have the following table:

Table: Products

```
ID |    Name   | Price | Price_mode |

0  | product1  | 150   |     1      |
1  | product2  | 5     |     2      |
2  | product3  | 8     |     2      |
```

And i want to order the products by `price` DESC **but** if `price_mode` is "2", i want the price to be multiplied by a number, say 20 for example.

With this criteria, the table should be ordered like: product3, product1, product2.

I hope you understood my question and thanks ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with expressions in the `order by`:

```
order by (case when price_mode = 2 then price * 20 else price end) desc
```